# What does "Normal distribution conditioned on $x \mod 1$" mean?

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, conditioning

I understand what $Pr[X = x | Y = y]$ means, however, on [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/837.pdf#page=18) (Lemma 10 in Appendix A), we have the following:

Let $D_r$ denote the continuous Gaussian distribution of parameter $r$,i.e.,  the law  over $\mathbb{R}$ with density function 
$$x \mapsto \frac{e^{−\pi x^2/r^2}}{r}.$$

> If $x \leftarrow D_r$, then the distribution of $x$ conditioned on $x \mod 1$ is within statistical distance $O(\epsilon)$ of $D_{\mathbb{Z}, r}$.

There, $D_{\mathbb{Z}, r}$ is a discrete Normal distribution over $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\epsilon$ and $r$ satisfy the relations $\epsilon > 0$ and  $r \ge \Omega(\sqrt{\ln{1/\epsilon}})$. Moreover, $x \mod 1$ is an operation that removes the "integer part" of $x$ mapping it to $[0, 1[$. For example, $1.9 \mod 1 = 0.9$ and $-2.3 \mod 1 = 0.7$. But those facts are not very important.

What I would like to know is how to interpret $x$ conditioned on $x \mod 1$. It does not seem to make sense to interpret it as $Pr[D_r = x | x \mod 1]$ since the "condition part" is not an equality.

Have you already seen that before? Do you know what it means?

Comment: For many definitions of conditional probability there's nothing to explain, so please tell us what definition you are working with.

Comment: The paper does not say with which definition it is working. If you know some definition for which that makes sense, could you please tell me?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=conditional+sigma+algebra+score%3A5 for the highest-voted posts we have on this subject.